# Magento Using filters in REST API doesn't show results

Tags: magento, rest, filter

I'm trying to use REST API with filters but apparently it doesn't work.

With `http://192.168.10.99/api/rest/products/2` I get the following result:

```
<magento_api>
<entity_id>2</entity_id>
<type_id>simple</type_id>
<sku>2</sku>
<name>Borsa Gucci</name>
<meta_title/>
<meta_description/>
<size_intl>16</size_intl>
<description>borsa gucci</description>
<short_description>borsetta</short_description>
<meta_keyword/>
<tier_price/>
<is_in_stock>0</is_in_stock>
<regular_price_with_tax>1000</regular_price_with_tax>
<regular_price_without_tax>1000</regular_price_without_tax>
<final_price_with_tax>1000</final_price_with_tax>
<final_price_without_tax>1000</final_price_without_tax>
<is_saleable>0</is_saleable>
<image_url>
http://192.168.10.99/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg
</image_url>
<url>
http://192.168.10.99/index.php/catalog/product/view/id/2/s/borsa-gucci/
</url>
<buy_now_url>
http://192.168.10.99/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMTAuOTkvYXBpL3Jlc3QvcHJvZHVjdHMvMg,,/product/2/form_key/wbRnSbkWsgjNy7KT/
</buy_now_url>
<total_reviews_count>0</total_reviews_count>
<has_custom_options/>
</magento_api>
```

If then I try `http://192.168.10.99/api/rest/products?filter[0][attribute]=entity_id&filter[0][in]=2` I get the following result:

*This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

< magento_api/>*

Where I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Alexio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've figured out what was the problem.

Without filters if the products exists in Magento it will be showed, but using filters it also need to be in stock (if you do manage stock).

Nice experience of debugging Magento even if the issue wasn't a bug :-)

Comment: Thats why! Btw. If you need to show out of stock products, change setting in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock options > Display out of stock products` and rebuild indices (based on this [blog post](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/))